# How to configure OAuth authorization URL

Tags: open-liberty, microprofile

I have a JAX-RS app using MP-OpenApi to provide an OpenAPI UI using OpenLiberty. My API is authenticated using OAuth2 implicit flow. This is currently configured using annotations, like this:

```
@SecurityScheme(
    securitySchemeName = JaxRsApplication.OAUTH2_SECURITY_SCHEME_NAME,
    type = SecuritySchemeType.OAUTH2,
    flows = @OAuthFlows(
            implicit = @OAuthFlow(
                    authorizationUrl = "https://auth-server/connect/authorize",
                    scopes = @OAuthScope(name = "some-api-scope", description = "Some API Scope"))))
```

My goal is to configure the authorizationUrl value in a config file instead of hardcoding it within an annotation, so that I can configure this for different server environments as a CI/CD step. Can this be done?

Also, is there a way to select some scopes and automatically populate the client id in the OpenAPI UI?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### To override the URL

Regarding to the [Microprofile OpenAPI Spec: OASFilter](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/microprofile-openapi-spec.adoc#oasfilter), we are able to override the `authorizationUrl` as the following example: -

```java
package my.filter;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.Config;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.OASFilter;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.models.security.SecurityScheme;

public class DemoOASFilter implements OASFilter {
    @Override
    public SecurityScheme filterSecurityScheme(final SecurityScheme securityScheme) {
        Config config = ConfigProvider.getConfig();
        String myUrl  = config.getValue("my.url", 
                                        String.class);
        securityScheme.getFlows().
                       getImplicit().
                       setAuthorizationUrl(myUrl);

        return securityScheme;
    }
}
```

Then put our fully qualified class name as a value of the `mp.openapi.filter` at the `META-INF/microprofile-config.properties` as the following example

```
mp.openapi.filter=my.filter.DemoOASFilter
my.url=http://some/url
```

Not only to override the `authorizationUrl`, the [OAuthFlow](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/openapi/models/security/OAuthFlow.java) also provide us to override the `tokenUrl`, `refreshUrl` and so on. Apart from the `implicit`, the [OAuthFlows](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/openapi/models/security/OAuthFlows.java) also provides the `authorizationCode`, `clientCredentails` and others as well. Furthermore the [OASFilter](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/openapi/OASFilter.java) interface give us to override more, e.g. `APIResponse`, `tag`, `server`, etc., too.

#### Integrate with `Microprofile: Config`

```java
Config config = ConfigProvider.getConfig();
String myUrl  = config.getValue("my.url", 
                                String.class);
```

I've tried to put the URL configuration to the `META-INF/microprofile-config.properties` as the above example, but not achieved as it give me a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

Anyhow the `environment variable` and `system properties` are achieved.

```bash
docker run -it \
    --env my.url=http://some/url \
    ....

java -Dmy.url=http://some/url -jar  ....
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was missing. I will give all of this a try. Thank you!